# How to cope with jitter when using Android-Universal-Image-Loader in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I'm using `Android-Universal-Image-Loader` in a `ListView` of mine and I'm trying to find the best solution to following:

- using `resetViewBeforeLoading` is necessary or else I get the same image in my `ConvertViews`, but this causes jitter, unless..
- I use `PauseOnScrollListener` which is otherwise great, except that it shows a blank in some `ConvertViews` even for images that are already downloaded (I'm using memory and disk caches), so it's confusing to the user who sees a blank for an image they saw only 2 swipes ago

So it seems that I can't get an instant image load (for already-downloaded images) on scroll without jitter, even for images in memory, is this about right? Is there a better or more standard way to do this? (Vertical list-view showing screen-width images, sort of like the Instagram app, which does it buttery-smooth)

Otherwise, is there a way to lengthen the number of convertViews in my ListView to prevent unnecessarily aggressive re-use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use AQuery for async image loading and which is also provide various cache option :http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: use ViewHolder for removing jittering in android listview/gridview